# Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I try to send the java String messages with kafka producer. And String messages are extracted from Java spark JavaPairDStream.

```
JavaPairDStream<String, String> processedJavaPairStream = inputStream.mapToPair
                 (record-> new Tuple2<>(record.key(), record.value())).mapValues(message -> message.replace('>', '#'));

String outTopics = "outputTopic";
String broker = "localhost:9092";

Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.put("bootstrap.servers", broker);
properties.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
properties.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");

Producer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer<String, String>(properties);
processedJavaPairStream.foreachRDD(rdd -> rdd.foreach(tuple2 -> {

    ProducerRecord<String, String> message = new ProducerRecord<String, String>(outTopics, tuple2._1, tuple2._2);

    System.out.println(message.key() + " : " + message.value()); //(1)

    producer.send(message).get(); //(2)
}));
```

(1) line print the message string correctly. But when I send these messages with kafka producer like (2) line, it throws the exception like below,

```
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer
Serialization stack:
    - object not serializable (class: org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer, value: org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer@10f6530d)
    - element of array (index: 1)
    - array (class [Ljava.lang.Object;, size 2)
    - field (class: java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda, name: capturedArgs, type: class [Ljava.lang.Object;)
    - object (class java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda, SerializedLambda[capturingClass=class com.aaa.StreamingKafkaDataWithSpark.streaming.SimpleDStreamExample, functionalInterfaceMethod=org/apache/spark/api/java/function/VoidFunction.call:(Ljava/lang/Object;)V, implementation=invokeStatic com/aaa/StreamingKafkaDataWithSpark/streaming/SimpleDStreamExample.lambda$3:(Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/apache/kafka/clients/producer/Producer;Lscala/Tuple2;)V, instantiatedMethodType=(Lscala/Tuple2;)V, numCaptured=2])
    - writeReplace data (class: java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda)
    - object (class com.aaa.StreamingKafkaDataWithSpark.streaming.SimpleDStreamExample$$Lambda$941/0x000000010077e440, com.aaa.StreamingKafkaDataWithSpark.streaming.SimpleDStreamExample$$Lambda$941/0x000000010077e440@7bb180e1)
    - element of array (index: 0)
    - array (class [Ljava.lang.Object;, size 1)
    - field (class: java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda, name: capturedArgs, type: class [Ljava.lang.Object;)
    - object (class java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda, SerializedLambda[capturingClass=interface org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike, functionalInterfaceMethod=scala/Function1.apply:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;, implementation=invokeStatic org/apache/spark/api/java/JavaRDDLike.$anonfun$foreach$1$adapted:(Lorg/apache/spark/api/java/function/VoidFunction;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;, instantiatedMethodType=(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;, numCaptured=1])
    - writeReplace data (class: java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda)
    - object (class org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$$Lambda$942/0x000000010077c840, org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$$Lambda$942/0x000000010077c840@7fb1cd32)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$.improveException(SerializationDebugger.scala:41)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializationStream.writeObject(JavaSerializer.scala:46)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.serialize(JavaSerializer.scala:100)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:400)
    ... 30 more
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:403)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:393)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:162)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2326)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$foreach$1(RDD.scala:926)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:363)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.foreach(RDD.scala:925)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike.foreach(JavaRDDLike.scala:351)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike.foreach$(JavaRDDLike.scala:350)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.AbstractJavaRDDLike.foreach(JavaRDDLike.scala:45)
    at com.aaa.StreamingKafkaDataWithSpark.streaming.SimpleDStreamExample.lambda$2(SimpleDStreamExample.java:72)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaDStreamLike.$anonfun$foreachRDD$1(JavaDStreamLike.scala:272)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaDStreamLike.$anonfun$foreachRDD$1$adapted(JavaDStreamLike.scala:272)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.$anonfun$foreachRDD$2(DStream.scala:628)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.$anonfun$foreachRDD$2$adapted(DStream.scala:628)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream.$anonfun$generateJob$2(ForEachDStream.scala:51)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.createRDDWithLocalProperties(DStream.scala:416)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream.$anonfun$generateJob$1(ForEachDStream.scala:51)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:213)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.Job.run(Job.scala:39)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler.$anonfun$run$1(JobScheduler.scala:257)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:62)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler.run(JobScheduler.scala:257)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

I can not understand this exception. I confirm the kafaka producer messages are `<String,String>` type with line (1). But why does line (2) throw this exception? Do I miss any process?

Comment: Plz, this may not be the answer. I am actually learning kafka recently. So want to learn. I have not seen where the get() is called on the kafka producer to send message or producerrecord. Remove the get() and check.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But I already test it without get function. But same exception

Comment: Are the tuples you are passing in String values? And shouldn't it be pair of <topic, message> for producer records? If the tuples arent String, you will need the String you want to pass in from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create the producer for each RDD.

RDDs are distributed over multiple executors, and a Producer object cannot be serialized to be shared amongst them

---

Alternatively, look at the [documentation of Structured Streaming](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html#writing-data-to-kafka) and you could simply do this to write into a topic; no need to create and send records yourself

```
stream.writeStream().format("kafka")...
```

Note that if the goal is simply to map one topic into another, [Kafka Streams API](https://kafka.apache.org/23/documentation/streams/tutorial)

is much simpler and less overhead than Spark

Comment: Could you share some sample codesy

Comment: Please refer to the duplicate post I linked to